# Speedup SQL query with join and like

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Is there a possibility to speedup a SQL-query like the following one?

```
SELECT....
FROM A, B, C
WHERE 
A.a = B.a AND
B.b like '%'+C.a+'%'
```

Comment: if A,B,C are related between them you better use an Inner Join

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso this already is an inner join. It's not in the most desirable syntax, but what do you think this is, an outer join?

Comment: Can you show some examples of the data in B.b and C.a? Also are there indexes on A.a, B.a, or B.b? What part of the operation is slow? Have you looked at the execution plan?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have added an aswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try to avoid 'like'.
- User Inner Join.
- Create indexes on Table A.a and B.a

  ```
  SELECT ...
  FROM A INNER JOIN B
  ON A.a = B.a
  INNER JOIN C
  ON B.b LIKE '%'+C.a+'%'
  ```

Comment: Why `B.a = C.a`? I think you've significantly changed the semantics of this query...

Answer (score 1):

While I would much rather see this syntax (since it is far less likely to inadvertently lead to a cross join):

```
SELECT A.a, B.a, B.b, C.a
  FROM A
  INNER JOIN B
    ON A.a = B.a
  INNER JOIN C
    ON B.b LIKE '%' + C.a + '%';
```

If the expensive part of this query is the `LIKE` operation, there's not really much you can do, since this specific pattern will require a scan every time. Can you show some examples of the data in B.b and C.a? Also are there indexes on A.a, B.a, or B.b?